# Spout library, get row / cell style

Tags: excel

I only managed to find how to set a style for a cell, but not how to get the style of a cell while reading a file.

I am currently reading files with hundreds of thousands of rows that may contain, at their end, a bunch of lines with yellow background (that display totals). I need to automatically find them and delete / stop processing the file.

I can't find in the documentation and online anything about this...
Thanks for any help

Comment: At this moment, this is not possible to do that with Spout unfortunately.